# Get variable from $this->variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get PHP class property by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804850/get-php-class-property-by-string)
>   [PHP method chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

I've got a class where a method returns the instance it's called on. How can I access a property (whose name is stored in a variable) directly from the return value of the function? Here's what I'm trying now:

```
class MyClass {
    public $variable_one;

    public function function_one() {
        $variable = 'last';
        // The problematic line: call method, access property on result
        return $this->function_two->$variable;
    }

    public function function_two($params = array()) {
        if (is_array($params)) {
            $params = http_build_query($params, NULL, '&');
        }

        $this->option(CURLOPT_COOKIE, $params);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `$this->some_function->$variable`?

Comment: Hi @bfavaretto i can't edited my question. Please see this http://pastebin.com/E0Rh8TpX

Comment: I think you're looking for method chaining. Please see the link above.

Comment: your script contains some errors, the $variable is not set within the class only with method, you need define variable. but if you want to call function_two then returns local variable. then you can't use chaining.  only if your variable defined within class scope then you can use chaining.  also function_two lacks the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The `$this` variable is *special* and only exists within classes. If you have a property within a class named variable, then you can access it with `$this->variable` from within that class.

```
class MyClass
{
   private $variable;
   public function getVariable()
   {
       return $this->variable;
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't edited my question. Please see this http://pastebin.com/E0Rh8TpX