# PHP: Dynamic Object Names

Tags: php, generics, object, dynamic, scalar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get PHP class property by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804850/get-php-class-property-by-string)

This is my original code:

```
function generateQuery($type, $language, $options)
{
    // Base type
    $query = $this->Queryparts->print['filter'];

    // Language modifiers
    // Additional options

    return $query;
}
```

The "print" is an array/hash defined as an object (with "(object)" casting). I wish to do something like this:

```
    $query = $this->Queryparts->$type['filter'];
```

To use the the $type variable  as the object name. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried or are you asking one of us to try?

Comment: @eisberg I tried. Didn't get any return value.

Comment: @Jonas Ballestad This sounds like your error reporting is off or low.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$query = $this->Queryparts->{$type}['filter'];
```

Answer (score 13):

You can either use an intermediary variable:

```
$name = 'something';
$object->$name;
```

Or you can use braces:

```
$a = array('foo' => 'bar');
$object->{$a['foo']}; //equivalent to $object->bar
```

(By the way, if you find yourself doing this often, there might be a design problem.)

Comment: Ok. I might have been a little unclear ($type = 'print') This solved my problem though: "$query = $this->Queryparts->{$type}['filter'];" I am not sure how your first example would be used in my case.

Comment: @JonasBallestad Ah, my bad.  I misunderstood the question.  I thought you were trying to use `$type['filter']` as the key.  Not access `Queryparts->{$type}` and then access the key `filter` of what is returned from that.  The idea of using {} stays the same though.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can, here is simple example:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Test = new stdClass();
$obj->Test->testing['arr'] = 'test';

$type = 'testing';
print_r($obj);
print_r($obj->Test->{$type});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use variable variable names by typing `$$` :

```
$a = array('car', 'plane');
$varname = 'a';
var_dump($$varname);
```