# Accessing PHP valiables fields names without using intermediate variables

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get PHP class property by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804850/get-php-class-property-by-string)

Is there a cleaner way to do this? it does not compile

```
$object1->name = 'my_name';
$object1->address = 'address';
$object2->somefield->($object1->name) = $object1;
```

it works only if i assign to another variable $object1->name

```
$object1->name = 'my_name';
$object1->address = 'address';
$temp = $object1->name;
$object2->somefield->$temp = $object1;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$object2->somefield->{$object1->name} = $object1;
```

Comment: +1, even this answer got too much up-votes :P

Comment: Good! Thank you!! It there some documentation to this somewhere? :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (under the 'Complex (curly) syntax' title)