# Use Variable in object echo

Tags: php, json

```
$data = file_get_contents("API LINK HERE");
$json = json_decode($data);

echo($json->zhohar->name);
```

What I want to do is replace `zhohar` in the `echo` with a variable which is defined by user input. So in the end I have something like this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

$data = file_get_contents("API LINK HERE");
$json = json_decode($data);

echo($json->$username->name);
```

But this obviously doesn't work. Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804850/get-php-class-property-by-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
echo $json->{$username}->name
```

Or:

```
$json = json_decode( $data, true );
echo $json[$username]['name'];
```

Comment: @dm03514 You're right, my bad.

Comment: @vplusm Welcome, but actually I shouldn't answer this one as it is duplicated and has been already answered before.