# php syntax enclosing brackets

Tags: php

Simple question:
I've been exploring open source code and saw the following statement:

```
$this->{$worker}
```

What is the meaning of enclosing brackets around, and what is the difference  between this and:

```
$this->worker
```

Comment: `$worker = 'somevar';` so `$this->{$worker} == $this->somevar`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get PHP class property by string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804850/get-php-class-property-by-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces are used for string or variable interpolation in PHP.

Something like

```
$worker = 'foo';
$this->{$worker} = 'bar';
```

that means

```
$this->foo = 'bar';
```

---

### When is useful

```
class RandomName
{
    protected $foo;
    protected $bar;
    protected $foo_bar;

    $properties_array = array('foo', 'bar', 'foo_bar');
    if (in_array($property, $properties_array)) {
        $this->{$property} = //some value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one actually uses the value of the variable `$worker`, while the latter uses the Expression / word `worker` to target the object property.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is using a variable as the attribute name. The second example is using a non-variable name for an attribute on your class.