# how to concatenate variable with database field name in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, variables, concatenation, laravel-blade

I'm using from laravel localization to switch between two languages and dynamically retrieve the data according to the selected language.
the database field names are `name_en, detail_en` in English Language and `name_pe, detail_pe` in Persian Language, So I want to get the `en and pe` from session and save into variable `$lng` and then concatenate it to the database field in blade file.

```
  @php
    $lng = Session::get('local');
    // will return en or pe
    @endphp

@foreach ($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="self_delall" id="self_delall" type="checkbox" name="delid[]" value="{{ $product->id }}"/>
    </td>
    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->name_.$lng }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->detail_.$lng }}</td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('products.show',$product->id) }}">Show</a>
        @can('product-edit')
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('products.edit',$product->id) }}">Edit</a>
        @endcan

        @can('product-delete')
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete/{{ $product->id }}/1">Delete</a>
        @endcan
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

So it return only the value of `$lng` instead of retrieve the database field value 
the output is here: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you call the property of the object. You want to get the *name_en* or *name_pe* from `$product` object.

When you do `$product->name_.$lng`, what actually happen is the PHP get the value of `$product->name_` and then add it with the value in $lng. In this case, the `$product->name_` is NULL and $lng is *en* or *pe* that why the output is either *en* or *pe*.

So, the solution is, you should change the way you call the attribute with `$product['name_' . $lng]` or prepare a variable `$column = 'name_' . $lng; $product->$column;` or you can do this `$product->{'name_' . $lng}`.

You can refer the operation from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804850/get-php-class-property-by-string).

Comment: Sure, I'm glad it helps you!

Comment: That last bit with the $product->{'name_' . $lng} was the life saver! Thank you.