# Merge two PHP tags

Tags: php

I want to convert two different PHP tags into a single PHP tag.This may sound a little weird but recently I found a question like this and answer with correct marked.

I can't find I'm currently lost address.

My question:

for example;

`$gates = array('t1','t2','t3',t4','t5');`

`$openGates->` and `$gates` merge.

Result:

`$openGates->t1;` or t2,t3.

If I remember correctly, the answer to the problem I found before was;

`$openGates->{$gates};` like this. I not sure

How can I do that?

Comment: I think you are mixing up the idea of arrays and objects. If you want to use $openGates->t1 then you will need a class of some kind. Look up PHP OOP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get PHP class property by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804850/get-php-class-property-by-string)

Answer (score 0):

It's not simple for newbie programmer...

At first:

```
$gates = array('t1','t2','t3','t4','t5');
```

It's Array

```
$openGates->
```

This is class instance. Btw. You can retrieve class instance var like `$className->varName`

You can't simple merge array and class instance. But you can create new class instance variables by loop.

```
foreach($gates as $gateKey=>$gateVal) {
    $openGates->$gatesVal = NULL;
}
```

But I think it's, in result should be like that:

```
 $gates = array('t1'=>'opened','t2'=>'closed','t3'=>'closed','t4'=>'opened','t5'=>'opened');
foreach($gates as $gateKey=>$gateVal) {
    $openGates->$gateKey = $gateVal;
}

echo $openGates->t1;

// or

foreach($gates as $key=>$val) {
    echo $openGates->$key.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Btw you can simple set `$openGates->gates = $gates;` and call it like `echo $openGates->gates['t1'];`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing objects with arrays. Arrays simply contain data, unless you create them with keys also. Such as:

`$gates = array('t1'=>true,'t2'=>false,'t3'=>"maybe",'t4'=>0,'t5'=>50);`

Matthew Page is correct in that you should look up [PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for a solution.

That being said, you can cast your array to an object providing it has both keys and values:

`$gates = (object) array('t1'=>true,'t2'=>false,'t3'=>"maybe",'t4'=>0,'t5'=>50);`

or

`$openGates = (object) $gates;`

This will allow you to access 'properties' of the object in the way you have demonstrated:

`echo $openGates->t1;`, for example. The `->` operator only applies to objects, which are instances of classes, not arrays.

If you do cast your array to the type of *object*, be sure that you have both keys and values.