# php update nested property in stdClass

Tags: php, reference, nested, stdclass

I have a stdClass object `$patient` that is the result of a webservice call. I also have an array of changes `$changes` that I want to make to that object.  But I can't get a reference to the nested properties the way I want. The stdClass looks something like this:

```
"Patient": {
    "PatientID": 649,
    "PatientClinicalInfo": {
        "Gender": "Male",
    },
    "PatientGeneralInfo": {
        "BillingAddress": {
            "AddressLine1": "123 MAIN ST",
            "AddressLine2": "APT B",
            "City": "SPRINGFIELD",
            "PostalCode": "49024",
            "State": "MI"
        },
        "BillingContactInfo": {
            "EmailAddress": "user@domain.com",
            "PhoneNumber": "3185189415"
        },
        "DeliveryAddress": {
            "AddressLine1": "123 MAIN ST",
            "AddressLine2": "APT B",
            "City": "SPRINGFIELD",
            "PostalCode": "49024",
            "State": "Michigan"
        },
        "DeliveryPhone": "3185189415",
        "Name": {
            "First": "Gonna",
            "Last": "Sick",
            "Middle": "B"
        }
    }
}
```

The array of changes looks something like this:

```
['delivery_address2' => 'APT 2B', 'primary_phone' => '2695551212']
```

This is what I was hoping to do *(but this code does not work)*:

```
private function applyChangesToPatient(array $changes, stdClass $patient): stdClass
{
    $newPatient = $patient;
    $fieldMap = [
        'delivery_address1' => 'PatientGeneralInfo->DeliveryAddress->AddressLine1',
        'delivery_address2' => 'PatientGeneralInfo->DeliveryAddress->AddressLine2',
        'primary_phone'     => 'PatientGeneralInfo->BillingContactInfo->PhoneNumber',
    ];
    foreach ($changes as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fieldMap[$key])){
            $path = $fieldMap[$key];
            $newPatient->$path = $value;  // This doesn't work!
        }
    }
    return $newPatient;
}
```

### What I've tried

There are lots of tips on stack**overflow** for iterating through the object and get the **values**, that's not what I want.
I've tried lots of different combinations of `$$path` and `${$path}`, but I just can't seem to convert the string `'PatientGeneralInfo->DeliveryAddress->AddressLine1'` to an actual *reference* to that property in the stdClass.

I have tried this, and it works. But I don't like it.

```
private function applyChangesToPatient(array $changes, stdClass $patient): stdClass
{
    $newPatient = $patient;
    foreach ($changes as $key => $value) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'delivery_address2':
                $newPatient->PatientGeneralInfo->DeliveryAddress->AddressLine2 = $value;
                break; 
            case 'primary_phone':
                $newPatient->PatientGeneralInfo->BillingContactInfo->PhoneNumber = $value;
                break;
           // etc. etc.
        }
    }
    return $newPatient;
}
```

I really want to use that `$fieldMap` array.  If that works, I can store the mapping in a separate JSON file and then easily add new mappings when needed -- without the need to change my code!

So, stack**overflow** Community?   Can you help me?

Comment: You're not going to find anything easier or more concise than what you have there. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41661733/1255289) which is a decent attempt at fetching dynamic property at arbitrary depth based on a string input.

Comment: @miken32 Thank you!  I was able to modify the code from [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41661733/1255289), to allow me to set the variable. Interestingly, I was only able to do it with a `$this` variable.  If I tried to pass the stdClass object, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Not mine, I just cleaned it up some. Glad you figured something out.