# PHP array_filtered acces object

Tags: php, arrays, object, filter, cascading

I'm trying to filter array from DB and I've got this postman response:

```
{
"1": {
    "id": "3",
    "key": "emails_html_body_start",
    "value": "value"
}}
```

How I can access to id, key, value?
My code here:

```
$start = array_filter($array, function ($var) {
    return ($var['key'] == 'emails_html_body_start');
}); 
echo json_encode($start);
```

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to Code, Data or Error Messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804850/get-php-class-property-by-string

Comment: `array_filter()` returns an array. Use `var_dump()` to print it, not `echo`.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear ... So the upper code is what is sent by the lower code snippet? So the `cho json_encode($start);` is what produces the upper json data? If so, then you obviously need to json decode that data again to be able to access a property inside that structure.

Comment: It would be useful to have the input an expected output.   As far as I can tell this does exactly what you coded it to do,  Given a multidimensional array with many elements like this (id, key, value), I would expect exactly what you got based on the code I see.   Everything except what is in your JSON (output) would be removed because `$var['key'] == 'emails_html_body_start'` would apparently be false.  Therefore the error must be in your logic ( what you expect ), which is a mystery at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit unclear ... So the upper code is what is sent by the lower code snippet? So the `cho json_encode($start);` is what produces the upper json data?

If so, then you obviously need to json decode that data again to be able to access a property inside that structure:

```
<?php
$input = <<<JSON
{
  "1": {
    "id": "3",
    "key": "emails_html_body_start",
    "value": "value"
  }
}
JSON;
$data = json_decode($input, true);
$output = $data[1]['id'];
print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

> 3